# cannot install configuration profile on iphone: "configuration profile installation failed"

Tags: windows, iphone, ios, config-files

We created a `new profile` for accessing our exchange using client certificates. The iPhone is connected localy to the windows pc. Trying to send the profile the iPhone configuration program says sometimes `Configuration profile installation failed`. (Mostly it says nothing and does nothing)

After exportig the profile we tried to `place it on our webserver`. When I access the url in safari, the safari tab closes without doing anything.

I found some inforations about this error which describe the `cleaning cache files on Apple OS`. I use `windows 7 and none of the described files were found there'.

Already tried reinstalling the software without any changes. Sending the file with mail would be an option, but I want to avoid this way.

Thanks for any suggestions!

Its IOS the latest 8.1 with iphone configration 3.6.2.300

**EDIT:**

As described above, the installation of the configuration file fails also when its on a webserver. So the problem is possibly not in the confiration software on windows but in the ios.

May there be a `setting which forbids importing new profiles`?

... or a conflict with an app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was finally easy. We saw that in the `iPhone configuration program` the field `unique ID` was empty event though it's a mandantory field. We deleted the profile an create a new one an everything worked fine.

(note: I don't know the correct translation for the field and used `unique ID` here. In German its called `Kennung`. Maybe somebody can correct the name in this post)